# Distribution (CDF) estimation for strictly increasing, continuous distribution with compact support

Tags: bootstrap, kernel-smoothing, maximum-entropy, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

For all $t\in 1,\dots,T$, suppose $x_t\in [0,1]$ is a draw from a distribution with unknown CDF $F:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$. For future use, define $\tilde{x}\in [0,1]^T$ to be a vector containing $x_1,\dots,x_T$ sorted into increasing order.

Suppose further that we know that $F$ is strictly increasing and continuous, and so has full support and no mass points.

The usual estimate of $F$ is the empirical CDF:
$$\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{E}}(z)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T{\mathbb{1}[x_t\le z]},$$
but this will neither be strictly increasing, nor continuous.

Now for $u,v\in [0,1]^T$, define $g_{u,v}:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ as the unique continuous, piecewise linear function with knot points at $0,u_1,\dots,u_T,1$ taking the values $0,v_1,\dots,v_T,1$, respectively.

Using this notation, we may define three other alternative estimators:
$$\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{L}}(y)=g_{\tilde{x},[0,\frac{1}{T},\frac{2}{T},\dots,\frac{T-1}{T}]}(y),$$
$$\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{H}}(y)=g_{\tilde{x},[\frac{1}{T},\frac{2}{T},\dots,1]}(y),$$
$$\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}(y)=g_{\tilde{x},[\frac{1}{T+1},\frac{2}{T+1},\dots,\frac{T}{T+1}]}(y).$$
All three estimators are continuous, but only $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}$ is strictly increasing.

Furthermore, it is easy to see that $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{L}}(y)\le\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{E}}\le\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{H}}$ and that $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{L}}(y)\le\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}\le\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{H}}$.

Asymptotically, all four estimators are equivalent, but in finite samples, my hunch is that $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}$ ought to perform better.

Can one give any justification for using $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}$ beyond the fact it is strictly increasing and continuous? E.g. it the maximum likelihood estimator of $F$ when $F$ is drawn from some reasonable distribution? Or is there some connection to maximum entropy?

I am tagging this with bootstrap, as the $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{E}}$ and $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{L}}$ estimators are used in constructing bootstrap p-values from source test p-values, and I am contemplating doing the same with the $\hat{F}_T^{\mathrm{M}}$ estimator.

---

**Edit: Suggestive evidence.**

Suppose that $F(z)=z$, and that $T=1$. Then:

$${\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{E}}\left( z \right)\mathbb{= 1}\left\lbrack x \leq z \right\rbrack$$

$${\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{L}}\left( z \right) = \min\left\{ \frac{z}{x},1 \right\}$$

$${\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{H}}\left( z \right) = \max\left\{ 0,\frac{z - x}{1 - x} \right\}$$

$${\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{M}}\left( z \right) = \min\left\{ \frac{z}{2x},\frac{1}{2} \right\} + \max\left\{ 0,\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1 - z}{2\left( 1 - x \right)} \right\}$$

$$\mathbb{E}{\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{E}}\left( z \right) = \int_{z}^{1}{0\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{1\mathbb{d}x} = z$$

$$\mathbb{E}{\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{L}}\left( z \right) = \int_{z}^{1}{\frac{z}{x}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{1\mathbb{d}x} = z - z\log z$$

$$\mathbb{E}{\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{H}}\left( z \right) = \int_{z}^{1}{0\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\frac{z - x}{1 - x}\mathbb{d}x} = z + \left( 1 - z \right)\log\left( 1 - z \right)$$

$$\mathbb{E}{\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{M}}\left( z \right) = \int_{z}^{1}{\frac{z}{2x}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\left\lbrack 1 - \frac{1 - z}{2\left( 1 - x \right)} \right\rbrack\mathbb{d}x} = z + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - z \right)\log\left( 1 - z \right) - \frac{1}{2}z\log z$$

$$\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{E}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2} = \int_{z}^{1}{\left( 0 - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\left( 1 - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} = z\left( 1 - z \right)$$

$$\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{L}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2} = \int_{z}^{1}{\left( \frac{z}{x} - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\left( 1 - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} = 2z\left( 1 - z + z\log z \right)$$

$$\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{H}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2} = \int_{z}^{1}{\left( 0 - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\left( \frac{z - x}{1 - x} - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} = 2\left( 1 - z \right)\left( z + \left( 1 - z \right)\log\left( 1 - z \right) \right)$$

$$\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{M}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2} = \int_{z}^{1}{\left( \frac{z}{2x} - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} + \int_{0}^{z}{\left( 1 - \frac{1 - z}{2\left( 1 - x \right)} - z \right)^{2}\mathbb{d}x} = z^{2}\log z + \left( 1 - z \right)^{2}\log\left( 1 - z \right) + \frac{3}{2}z\left( 1 - z \right)$$

The figure below plots $\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{E}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2}$ in red, $\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{L}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2}$ in dark blue, $\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{H}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2}$ in green and $\mathbb{E}\left( {\hat{F}}_{1}^{\mathrm{M}}\left( z \right) - F(z) \right)^{2}$ in light blue.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: Plots of MSE]

The $\mathrm{M}$ estimator has the lowest MSE despite its bias.

Ideally though, I would like to prove a result like this without making assumptions on what $F$ is. (Assumptions on the distribution from which $F$ is drawn are fine, providing they have full support on the class of distributions described. E.g. $F(z)=\frac{\int_0^z{(\exp{W(\tau)}+J(\tau))\mathbb{d}\tau}}{\int_0^1{(\exp{W(\tau)}+J(\tau))\mathbb{d}\tau}}$, where $W$ is standard Brownian motion and $J$ is a pure jump process with e.g. exponentially distributed jump sizes.)

Comment: Re "but this will neither be strictly increasing, nor continuous": a good reaction at this point ought to be "so what?"  Estimators do not have to, nor can be expected to, reproduce all the characteristics of the underlying distribution.  The right questions to be asking concern what properties these estimators have.  It's possible the usual empirical CDF is still best for whatever your statistical purposes might be, despite not being strictly increasing. This suggests that the answers to your questions might lie in a more detailed analysis of what statistic you're actually bootstrapping.

Comment: The question here is precisely asking for properties of the "M" estimator that make it superior to the "E", "L" and "H" estimators. The question gives one such property, that it is continuous and strictly increasing, but the very fact I'm asking this question should imply that I do not think it is particularly compelling on its own. That said, not sharing the properties of the quantity being estimated is a sign of possible econometric inefficiency, so I do not think your "so what" reaction is entirely justified.

Comment: In the bootstrap context, of course one good reason to use one of these tests rather than another is relative concern about type 1 vs type 2 error. "M" reflects a balanced concern.

Comment: I am asking in what sense you intend "superior" to be taken.  You haven't indicated anything about that.

Comment: Any (reasonable) sense in which it is! If you were forced at gunpoint to write a paper using the "M" estimator, how would you justify it?

Comment: E.g. is there a reasonable class of F for which the "M" estimator has lower mean squared / maximum absolute error?

Comment: Is it a particular estimator of a much more general (and widely used class)? E.g. is it an ML or MAP estimator with reasonable distributional and prior assumptions?

Comment: Hopefully the suggestive example I've just added makes it clearer still the kind of result I'm hoping for.